# Login User without a password

Tags: login, plugin, sessions

So I'm attempting to create a small plugin/module where I can log in a user with the need to have a password, login with Facebook basically (Yes, I know there is a plugin that does all this).

I was looking at this thread -> [Can't programmatically log member in](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2413/cant-programmatically-log-member-in)

Is all that I need to do to log a person in, is to call the create_new_session() function?

I can't seem to find any decent documentation on this. Any help or references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at code how ExpressionEngine does it from the Control Panel.

See the function do_login_as_member within the file expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php

Hope, it would help you lot.